# Angular 2 - Edit table rows inline, then save the new data

Tags: angular

I am trying to make a component that shows data in rows from TableData model,

```
export class TableData{
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public country: string,
        public capital: string){ }
}
```

I have my data in the component like this,

```
tableData: TableData[] = [
        new TableData(1, 'Canada','Ottawa'),
        new TableData(2, 'USA','Washington DC'),
        new TableData(3, 'Australia','Canberra'),
        new TableData(4, 'UK','London')
        ];
```

Then in my component, I am creating a table like this,

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="#row of tableData>
        <td contenteditable='true'>{{ row.id }}</td>
        <td contenteditable='true' (click)="onRowClick($event)">{{ row.country }}</td>
        <td contenteditable='true'>{{ row.capital }}</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
<span>{{ tableData | json }}</span>
</table>

onRowClick(event){
console.log(event);
}
```

I am able to edit the data as I marked the `<td>` element as 'contenteditable', but don't know how to save it or retrieve the updated values. I inspected 'event' data that's passed to onRowClick method, but couldn't retrieve the 'id' of row (it's empty. event.srcElement.id or event.target.id are both empty).

In short, I want to edit the table and see it update the tableData variable. Sorry for not asking it clearly the first time.

Any guidance on how to solve my problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't assign an id, why do you expect one to be set?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Juts pass `id` as flag along with your id then detect as per id clicked on the row of table here is example -

```
tableData: TableData[] = [
        new TableData('Canada','Ottawa',1),
        new TableData('USA','Washington DC',2),
        new TableData('Australia','Canberra',3),
        new TableData('UK','London',4)
        ];
```

- PS  - your code is throwing error here please correct here.

  `<tr *ngFor="#row of tableData>`

should be changed with

```
<tr *ngFor="#row of tableData">
```

working demo here 
<kbd>[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4UPlh9Pn42yM3VPqYvoL?p=preview)</kbd>

Update - 
Try using `(input)` event binding on the `td` and get the updated text using `event.target.outerText` . please check update plnukr.

```
<tr *ngFor="#row of tableData">
  <td contenteditable='true' (input)="onRowClick($event, row.id)">{{ row.country }}</td>
  <td contenteditable='true'>{{ row.capital }}</td>
</tr>

onRowClick(event, id){
    console.log(event.target.outerText, id);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am looking for something else, updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: your welcome. PS my updated answer hope it help you.

Comment: @PardeepJain Great solution! Can I change this to double click event instead of single click in some easy way?

Comment: Hi, your event in the of which type ?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking an answer to the same question. First, I got here.
Later, I found amazing article with answer you was looking for.

Updated: I have udpated plunk as well as directive code to latest verstion of angular

> Directive: contenteditableModel

```
<span contenteditable [(contenteditableModel)]="text"></span>
```

https://www.namekdev.net/2016/01/two-way-binding-to-contenteditable-element-in-angular-2/

https://plnkr.co/edit/SRLYoX5chNYJIpZ4iqsG?p=preview

```
import {
    Directive,
    ElementRef,
    Input,
    Output,
    OnChanges,
    EventEmitter,
    HostListener,
    SimpleChanges
} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * 
 */
@Directive({
    selector: '[contenteditableModel]'
})
export class ContenteditableModelDirective implements OnChanges {

    @Input('contenteditableModel')
    public model: any;

    @Output('contenteditableModelChange')
    public update = new EventEmitter();

    private _lastViewModel: any;

    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

    public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if(this._lastViewModel !== changes['model'].currentValue){
            this._lastViewModel = this.model;
            this._refreshView();
        }
    }

    @HostListener('blur')
    public onBlur() {
        var value = this.elRef.nativeElement.innerText;
        this._lastViewModel = value;
        this.update.emit(value);
    }

    private _refreshView() {
        this.elRef.nativeElement.innerText = this.model;
    }
}
```