# How to make text editable on links in d3

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, svg

```
this._link = this._linksEle.selectAll('.link').data(this._links);

        // enter selection
        let linkEnter = this._link.enter().append('g')
            .attr('id', function (d) {
                var linkObj = d.source['link_' + d.source.id + d.target.id];
                return linkObj.id;
            })
            .attr('source', function (d) {
                return d.source.id;
            })
            .attr('target', function (d) {
                return d.target.id;
            })
            .attr('class', 'link');

        // Enter links
        linkEnter.append('path')
            .attr('id', function (d) {
                return 'linkPath' + d.source.id + d.target.id;
            })
            .attr('class', 'link-path')
            .style('fill', 'none')
            .style('stroke', '#ccc')
            .style('stroke-width', 2)
            .style('cursor', 'pointer')
            .attr('marker-end', 'url(#path_arrow)')
            .on("click", function (d) {
                self.fnEdgeClick(d);
            });

        linkEnter.append('text').attr('class', 'edge-label')
            .attr({
                'dx': 110,
                'dy': -5,
                'font-size': 10,
                'fill': '#aaa'
            })
            .style('pointer-events', 'none')
            .append('textPath')
            .attr('xlink:href', function (d) {
                return '#linkPath' + d.source.id + d.target.id;
            })
            .style('pointer-events', 'none')
            .text(function (d) {
                var linkObj = d.source['link_' + d.source.id + d.target.id];
                return linkObj.relation ? linkObj.relation : 'Add relation';
            });
```

So far i added label on links its working fine but i need to add functionality to make them editable/rename. yet i did not find any relevant example. Can any body suggest a good working example so i can take help.

Comment: code you provided does't make any sense, also it is very messy, please make it more clear in order to understand your problem

Comment: please have a look here may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/36823304/5043867

Comment: @PardeepJain Jain i need this in d3

Comment: sorry i didn't even what is d3 ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `foreignObject` to implement editable texts inside SVG.

> **ForeignObject**: Enables content from another XML namespace to be inserted into an Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) namespace.
>    More Info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

```js
var width = 200,
  height = 200,
  margin = {
    left: 5,
    right: 5,
    top: 5,
    bottom: 5
  };

var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
  "name": "ken",
  "age": "40"
}, {
  "name": "Jen",
  "age": "40"
}];

chart.selectAll("text")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return (i + 1) + "em"
  })
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .append('xhtml:div')
  .append('div')
  .attr("contentEditable", true)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name
  });
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks @Gilsha but could not understand :( how to use it in my case .

Comment: You have not shared your complete code. That's why I created a snippet on my own. You just need to create foreignObject instead of SVG text elements. The exact line would be this `linkEnter.append('text')`. 
Replace above lines with the code to append foreignObject in the snippet.

Comment: @Gilsha Do you have any advice in terms of how to dynamically update a svg's id based on what is the innerHTML? I'm using your code template, but I'm having trouble thinking of how I can update its id.